# How can I monitor network traffic and browser activity

Tags: c++, c, windows, sockets, winapi

Firstly;
Let me share what I wanted to do and where I was struggling.

1.I want to track user movements in web browsers

2. In any browser, I want to save information about the website the user is logged on, package data (download / upload), the browser the    user is using.
3. I want to record information such as what protocol I mentioned in item 2, local port, local address and remote port, remote port name,    remote address, packets sent and packets received.

I shared what I wanted to do and what I could not.

The methods I tried;
I tried to do api hook operation in google chrome, edge, opera browsers.

I have applied the trampoline function method to winhttp.dll functions, but I could not get any data.

```
static  DWORD(WINAPI* MS_WinHttpWebSocketReceive)(HINTERNET hWebSocket,
                                                  PVOID pvBuffer,
                                                  DWORD dwBufferLength,
                                                  DWORD* pdwBytesRead,
                                                  WINHTTP_WEB_SOCKET_BUFFER_TYPE* peBufferType
                                                  ) = WinHttpWebSocketReceive;

static DWORD WINAPI MY_WinHttpWebSocketReceive(HINTERNET hWebSocket,
                                              PVOID pvBuffer,
                                              DWORD dwBufferLength,
                                              DWORD* pdwBytesRead,
                                              WINHTTP_WEB_SOCKET_BUFFER_TYPE* peBufferType)
{
  OutputDebugString(L"=====MY_WinHttpWebSocketReceive Start======");
  OutputDebugString(L"Succeed");
  OutputDebugString(L"=====MY_WinHttpWebSocketReceive End======");
  
  return MS_WinHttpWebSocketReceive(hWebSocket, pvBuffer, dwBufferLength, pdwBytesRead, peBufferType);
}
```

I tried the trampoline function method to many functions of winhttp.dll but failed.

Does anyone know which method they use in the application I shared an example?

[Browser and other infos...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTwCw.png)

[Packet etc infos](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Hpa.png)

How can I do what I want to do?

What dlls and functions do I need to hook up to get this information I want?

I want to save information such as protocol, local port, local address and remote port, remote port name, remote address, packets sent and packets received.

Show me the rabbit holes.

Comment: None of the browsers you mentioned use WinHTTP. They all use the Chrome engine, which has its own HTTP library.

Comment: The first five paragraphs of this question are just noise. They do not add anything useful to help illustrate the problem you are trying to solve. You can increase the chances of getting useful feedback by keeping the question focused.

Comment: Thank yo for comment @Botje.  So what should I do? Do you have any suggestions on this issue?

Comment: You need to completely rethink your approach. All modern websites use HTTPS so any interceptions at the network level will be randomly distributed noise. And of course developing spyware is unethical.

Comment: I allowed myself to remove the first two paragraphs, not sure about the rest. You don't need to tell us that we need to read the question and that you want an answer ;)

Comment: thank you for your advice @IInspectable I updated my question again and removed unnecessary paragraphs.  Please focus on my question and I need your idea and method to solve this problem, if any.

Comment: thank you for comment @idclev 463035818. I updated my question.
Well, do you have a solution for my question?

Comment: @RecaiCingöz You'll get an answer if someone that happens to know if it's possible reads the question and finds it interesting. Meanwhile others can help you to improve the question to make it more likely that this potential "someone" actually reads it through.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for an implementation similar to the [Network Monitor 3 tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/network-monitor-3).

You can start learning from [Windows Sockets 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-start-page-2). If you want to complete your project quickly, then you can focus on the following APIs.

[socket function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-socket), [bind function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-bind), [recvfrom function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-recvfrom), etc

Among them, the buffer accepted by `recvfrom` is what we need.

> The recvfrom function reads incoming data on both connected and
> unconnected sockets and captures the address from which the data was
> sent. This function is typically used with connectionless sockets.
>
> For message-oriented sockets, data is extracted from the first
> enqueued message, up to the size of the buffer specified. If the
> datagram or message is larger than the buffer specified, the buffer is
> filled with the first part of the datagram, and recvfrom generates the
> error WSAEMSGSIZE. For unreliable protocols (for example, UDP) the
> excess data is lost. For UDP if the packet received contains no data
> (empty), the return value from the recvfrom function function is zero.
>
> ..

Of course, we need a suitable example to help us run forward.

Some code:

```
typedef struct ip_hdr
{
    unsigned char ip_header_len : 4; // 4-bit header length (in 32-bit words) normally=5 (Means 20 Bytes may be 24 also)
    unsigned char ip_version : 4; // 4-bit IPv4 version
    unsigned char ip_tos; // IP type of service
    unsigned short ip_total_length; // Total length
    unsigned short ip_id; // Unique identifier

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset : 5; // Fragment offset field

    unsigned char ip_more_fragment : 1;
    unsigned char ip_dont_fragment : 1;
    unsigned char ip_reserved_zero : 1;

    unsigned char ip_frag_offset1; //fragment offset

    unsigned char ip_ttl; // Time to live
    unsigned char ip_protocol; // Protocol(TCP,UDP etc)
    unsigned short ip_checksum; // IP checksum
    unsigned int ip_srcaddr; // Source address
    unsigned int ip_destaddr; // Source address
} IPV4_HDR;

typedef struct udp_hdr
{
    unsigned short source_port; // Source port no.
    unsigned short dest_port; // Dest. port no.
    unsigned short udp_length; // Udp packet length
    unsigned short udp_checksum; // Udp checksum (optional)
} UDP_HDR;

// TCP header
typedef struct tcp_header
{
    unsigned short source_port; // source port
    unsigned short dest_port; // destination port
    unsigned int sequence; // sequence number - 32 bits
    unsigned int acknowledge; // acknowledgement number - 32 bits

    unsigned char ns : 1; //Nonce Sum Flag Added in RFC 3540.
    unsigned char reserved_part1 : 3; //according to rfc
    unsigned char data_offset : 4; /*The number of 32-bit words in the TCP header.
    This indicates where the data begins.
    The length of the TCP header is always a multiple
    of 32 bits.*/

    unsigned char fin : 1; //Finish Flag
    unsigned char syn : 1; //Synchronise Flag
    unsigned char rst : 1; //Reset Flag
    unsigned char psh : 1; //Push Flag
    unsigned char ack : 1; //Acknowledgement Flag
    unsigned char urg : 1; //Urgent Flag

    unsigned char ecn : 1; //ECN-Echo Flag
    unsigned char cwr : 1; //Congestion Window Reduced Flag

    ////////////////////////////////

    unsigned short window; // window
    unsigned short checksum; // checksum
    unsigned short urgent_pointer; // urgent pointer
} TCP_HDR;

...

int main()
{
    SOCKET sniffer;
    struct in_addr addr;
    int in;

    char hostname[100];
    struct hostent* local;
    WSADATA wsa;

    logfile = fopen("log.txt", "w");
    if (logfile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Unable to create file.");
    }

    //Initialise Winsock
    printf("\nInitialising Winsock...");
    if (WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsa) != 0)
    {
        printf("WSAStartup() failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Initialised");

    //Create a RAW Socket
    printf("\nCreating RAW Socket...");
    sniffer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_IP);
    if (sniffer == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Failed to create raw socket.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Created.");

    //Retrive the local hostname
    if (gethostname(hostname, sizeof(hostname)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error : %d", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("\nHost name : %s \n", hostname);

    //Retrive the available IPs of the local host
    local = gethostbyname(hostname);
    printf("\nAvailable Network Interfaces : \n");
    if (local == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error : %d.\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    for (i = 0; local->h_addr_list[i] != 0; ++i)
    {
        memcpy(&addr, local->h_addr_list[i], sizeof(struct in_addr));
        printf("Interface Number : %d Address : %s\n", i, inet_ntoa(addr));
    }

    printf("Enter the interface number you would like to sniff : ");
    scanf("%d", &in);

    memset(&dest, 0, sizeof(dest));
    memcpy(&dest.sin_addr.s_addr, local->h_addr_list[in], sizeof(dest.sin_addr.s_addr));
    dest.sin_family = AF_INET;
    dest.sin_port = 0;

    printf("\nBinding socket to local system and port 0 ...");
    if (bind(sniffer, (struct sockaddr*) & dest, sizeof(dest)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("bind(%s) failed.\n", inet_ntoa(addr));
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Binding successful");

    //Enable this socket with the power to sniff : SIO_RCVALL is the key Receive ALL ;)

    j = 1;
    printf("\nSetting socket to sniff...");
    if (WSAIoctl(sniffer, SIO_RCVALL, &j, sizeof(j), 0, 0, (LPDWORD)&in, 0, 0) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("WSAIoctl() failed.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Socket set.");

    //Begin
    printf("\nStarted Sniffing\n");
    printf("Packet Capture Statistics...\n");
    StartSniffing(sniffer); 

    //End
    closesocket(sniffer);
    WSACleanup();

    return 0;
}
```

Complete code: [winsock sample](https://github.com/ECToo/world-opponent-network/blob/fbb35876ae26006606d07b6297d557bd53234066/%20world-opponent-network/TitanApi/Samples/ServerTest%20-%20Copy/Sniffer/main.cpp) (out of the box) **Don't forget to run as admin.**

You can also use the Network Monitor 3.4 tool to understand the buffer structure.

[image]

Comment: Hi,@Recai Cingöz did this answer work for you? Please feel free to [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it if it did help to you.

Comment: Hi @Strive Sun - MSFT. Your answer guided me. I started off with your answer and found different solutions. github.com/google/gopacket. Thanks for answer